# Next.js dynamic import not working with a variable as module path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using Next.js to build a web application, and I'm trying to load a component dynamically using the dynamic() function. The code works fine when I use a string literal as the module path, like this:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const ThreeComponent = dynamic(
  () => import('../../../shared/components/one/two/three/three.component'),
  { ssr: false }
);
```

However, when I try to use a variable for the module path, like this:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const pathurl = '../../../shared/components/one/two/three/three.component';
const ThreeComponent = dynamic(() => import(`${pathurl}`), { ssr: false });
```

I get an error that says "Error: Cannot find module".

I've checked that the path to the module is correct, and I'm using a version of Next.js that supports dynamic imports (version 9.4 or later). I've also tried using an absolute path or a relative path from the root of my project, but I still get the same error.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I load a module dynamically using a variable for the module path in Next.js?

As I explained in my problem, I am trying to run my code that is correct, but it is not working at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They say on the official [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) that the path should be explicitly set; it cannot be a template litterale, nor a variable:

> In `import('path/to/component')`, the path must be explicitly written. It can't be a template string nor a variable. Furthermore the `import()` has to be inside the `dynamic()` call for Next.js to be able to match webpack bundles / module ids to the specific `dynamic()` call and preload them before rendering.

If you want to handle different dynamic imports in one place, you could do something like below:

```js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const ComponentOne = dynamic(() => import("./One.js"), { ssr: false });
const ComponentTwo = dynamic(() => import("./Two.js"), { ssr: false });

export default function DynamicComponent({ componentNubmer = 1 }) {
  if (componentNubmer == 1) {
    return <ComponentOne />;
  }
  return <ComponentTwo />;
}
```

And use it like this to import `One.js`:

```js
<DynamicComponent componentNubmer={1} />
```